# C# NUnit SetUp and TearDown functions not running when using SpecFlow

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, specflow

I'm trying to create automated tests using NUnit and selenium, however I cannot get the SetUp and TearDown functions to work.

```
[Binding] [SetUpFixture]
public class AuthenticatorSteps
{
    IWebDriver _driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;
    string username;
    string password;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _driver = new ChromeDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _driver.Close();
    }

[Given(@"I am on the site")]
        public void GivenIAmOnTheSite()
        {
            _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://qa02-ukcasino.bedegaming.net");
            wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.CssSelector(AuthenticatorElements.LoginButton)));
        }
```

They just aren't being called at all. The code I'm using works if I put them inside the steps themselves, however that requires me to add a step eg. Then the browser should close, when I should be able to just use the TearDown function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is this a Unit Test?**
Change you `[SetUpFixture]` to be a `[TestFixture]`.
(note: If you are using NUnit 2.5 or great you can remove [TestFixture])

The later is used for one time setups and the former, for setups per test.

**Is this a SpecFlow test?**
I also assume you have set **SpecFlows** test runner to be *NUnit*.

You need to use the `BeforeScenario` or `BeforeFeature` attributes, rather than the NUnit ones.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Try using a [OneTimeSetUp] attribute on another method, does that work?
What version of NUnit are you using?
Can you add an example of a Test method?

Comment: Still not working. Here is one of my test methods, however I don't think this will help with anything as all of the tests pass if I get rid of the setup and teardown functions and add that code into test methods.

Comment: See my latest edit, you are running SpecFlow tests so need to use a different attribute :-)